# How to prove when Möbius transformation determinant ad - bc < 0, the upper half plane does not map to itself?

Tags: complex-analysis

I proved the part where $$\operatorname{Im}  f(z) = \frac {(ad -  bc) \operatorname{Im}z} {|cz + d|^2} $$

But now I need to show that when $ ad - bc < 0 $, then the upper half plane does not map to itself

Answer (score 4):

Try plugging in something in the upper half plane ($z=i$, for example).

Comment: Do you mean into the equation I posted and try to prove that LHS not equal RHS ?

Comment: @devcoder, No, you need to show that something with positive imaginary part maps to something with negative imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're asking how to prove, when $(ad-bc) = 0$, that at least one of:

- There exists a $z$ such that $\Im{z} > 0$, and $(ad-bc) \Im{z} / |cz+d|^2 < 0$,
- There exists a $z$ such that $\Im{z} > 0$ and the equation $f(w)=z$ has no solutions with $\Im{w} > 0$?